# How to render all products with certain spree taxons associated with them onto a template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Taking the Spree tutorial further, we would like to list all products and their children with a taxon name of "Soaps" to appear on our Soaps product page.  Looking into the database (table: spree_taxons), we found that the taxon ID for Soaps is "1", which also happens to be a parent.

This is what we created so far: /root/mystore/spree_simple_sales/app/controllers/spree/home_controller_decorator.rb

```
module Spree
   HomeController.class_eval do

#rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :render_404
helper 'spree/taxons'
helper 'spree/products'
respond_to :html

def sale
  @products = Product.joins(:variants_including_master).where('spree_variants.sale_price is not null').uniq
    end

def soaps
  @products = Product.joins(:variants_including_master).where('spree_taxons.id == 1').uniq
    end

 end
end
```

This is what we have within our template file:
/root/mystore/app/views/spree/home/soaps.html.erb

```
<% content_for :sidebar do %>
  <div data-hook="homepage_sidebar_navigation">
    <%= render :partial => 'spree/shared/taxonomies' %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div data-hook="homepage_products">
<img src="http://192.168.2.228:3000/assets/store/soaps_cover_photo.jpg" />

<p>Important information regarding the Soaps taxon goes here.</p>
<!-- code to render all products with soaps taxon (aka, taxon ID=1) -->
<%= render 'spree/shared/products', :products => @products %>
</div>
```

We think we our code is incorrectly written. Can someone tell us the syntax we need to display the Soaps taxon products and all their children correctly? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We were able to get this working by using the following code within our home_controller_decorator.rb file.

```
def soaps
      @products = Spree::Product.in_taxons(1)
      @taxonomies = Spree::Taxonomy.includes(root: :children)
    end
```